# Send pdf from Javascript function to ASP .Net controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net

So here is the thing, the following function generates the pdf of a required page and downloads it. Now what I want to do is that instead of downloading the pdf i want to send it to my controller from where I would send it as mail to selected people. Is this doable. If yes, please help me. If no, then i am open to suggestions of alternate solution. Thanks A lot

```
function getPDF(){

    var HTML_Width = $(".canvas_div_pdf").width();
    var HTML_Height = $(".canvas_div_pdf").height();
    var top_left_margin = 15;
    var PDF_Width = HTML_Width+(top_left_margin*2);
    var PDF_Height = (PDF_Width*1.5)+(top_left_margin*2);
    var canvas_image_width = HTML_Width;
    var canvas_image_height = HTML_Height;

    var totalPDFPages = Math.ceil(HTML_Height/PDF_Height)-1;


    html2canvas($(".canvas_div_pdf")[0],{allowTaint:true}).then(function(canvas) {
        canvas.getContext('2d');

        console.log(canvas.height+"  "+canvas.width);


        var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt',  [PDF_Width, PDF_Height]);
        pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPG', top_left_margin, top_left_margin,canvas_image_width,canvas_image_height);


        for (var i = 1; i <= totalPDFPages; i++) {
            pdf.addPage(PDF_Width, PDF_Height);
            pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPG', top_left_margin, -(PDF_Height*i)+(top_left_margin*4),canvas_image_width,canvas_image_height);
        }

        pdf.save("HTML-Document.pdf");
    });
};
```

Comment: What is a controller in this context?

Comment: I have not yet written the controller. It can be assumed as empty controller for now that will just accept the response of this pdf.

Comment: Controller... in JS?

Comment: The controller is of ASP .Net..

Comment: You’d have to send the data via a network request.

Comment: To send the PDF via email, [output it as datauristring](https://medium.com/@weihui.guo/save-html-page-and-online-images-as-a-pdf-attachment-with-one-click-from-client-side-21d65656e764).